# Orthogonality relation for adiabatic Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, adiabatic

Suppose we have a Hamiltonian dependent on a parameter.
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}(\lambda)=\hat{H}_{0}+\lambda \hat{V}
\end{equation}
We study how the energy eigenstates vary with the parameter by solving,
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}(\lambda)|n,\lambda\rangle=E_{n}(\lambda)|n,\lambda\rangle
\end{equation}
The eigenstates are normalized for $\langle m,\lambda|n,\lambda\rangle=\delta_{m,n}$. Appendix C
of the paper "BBGKY chain and kinetic equations for the level dynamics in an externally perturbed quantum system", https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02380 claims that,
\begin{equation}
\langle m,\lambda|\frac{d}{d\lambda}|m,\lambda\rangle=0
\end{equation}
but I can only show that the real part of this complex number is zero. Could someone show me how to prove the imaginary part is also zero?

Comment: Could you be more specific, in what equation precisely do they claim that?

Comment: Based on what you wrote, I don't think it is correct. As a counter-example you can have V=0 with a gauge varying with \lambda  as |\psi(\lambda)> = e^{i\lambda}|\psi(0)>

Comment: @nwolijin : In first sentence after equation (55).

Comment: @Stephen Blake I think I agree with you: if
$\langle n(t) | n(t) \rangle=1$, then $0=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\langle n(t) | n(t) \rangle=\langle \dot n(t) | n(t) \rangle+\langle n(t) | \dot n(t) \rangle=2\mathrm{Re}\langle n(t) | \dot n(t) \rangle$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the whole paper, but it appears that $\lambda$ is a function of time, and that the Hamiltonian $H$ depends on time only through $\lambda$. I say this because they appear to substitute $\langle m,\lambda|\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}|n,\lambda\rangle\dot\lambda$ for $\langle m,\lambda|\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|n,\lambda\rangle$ between equation 54 to equation 55, unless there's some non-trivial identity that is glossed over in that step. Under this assumption, the claim is not true. We can use the Schrödinger equation to prove otherwise:
$$E_m|m,\lambda\rangle=i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|m,\lambda\rangle=i\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}|m,\lambda\rangle\dot{\lambda}$$
$$\implies E_m\langle m,\lambda|m,\lambda\rangle=i\langle m,\lambda|\frac{\partial }{\partial\lambda}|m,\lambda\rangle\dot\lambda.$$
Unless $E_m=0$, $\langle m,\lambda|\frac{\partial }{\partial\lambda}|m,\lambda\rangle\dot\lambda\neq 0$.